# Build and publish web site project with VS 2012 and TFS 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web, msbuild

I am using VS 2012 and TFS 2010. I am trying to build a website project (NOT a web application project) and deploy it to a test web server.

When files get checked in, I want TFS to build the website and push it over to a test server (uncompiled).

I have found many posts indicating that I should use a web deployment project, but that doesn't seem to be an option for VS 2012. I also found that VS 2012 is supposed to have better support for website project deployment (.pubxml) which I can get to work great from inside Visual Studio, but the TFS 2010 build wants a project or solution file.

I am new to TFS so I may be missing something obvious here.

Comment: I am aware of that, unfortunately I have 10 years of code that I currently don't have the time or resources to convert to a web application, so I need a solution that works for the code I currently have.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution from the OP**:

I figured out my issue. There was a file create called `website.publishproj` that I needed to put into source control before turning on gated check-ins. I could then use that file for "Items to build".  TFS is at least now attempting to build the website.  It looks like I have some more configuration issues to get through.